How to run github runner in my linux server using forticlient vpn
I have a linux vm which is just created running ubuntu 22.04 server edition.
I had fortigate devices that connected to all my devices and network.
Recently, my software teams request the linux vm access to the Github CD/CI runner.
My software teams is working remotely. All the connection from outside using forticlient
VPN.
I allowed the SSH services on the FortiGate firewall but how I gonna bypass vpn for the Github CD/CI runner
